# почему well не натягивается всю ячейку

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не знаю, почему, но well стоит особняком от всей ячейки. Что я сделал не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="success">Продолжить</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если убрать нижнюю кнопку, и окружающую ее `<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">`, то все работает как надо. Bootstrap 3.3.6.

Comment: Какой результат вы пытаетесь достичь? Лучше показать картинкой.

Comment: В [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) нет класса `.row-fluid`. Как он у вас определён?

Comment: Вы правы, изменил row-fluid на row и все заработало как надо, почему то раньше считал что есть резиновая строка row :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На широком экране бутстраповские колонки получают свойство `float: left;` и родительский блок схлопывается. Есть два распространённых [способа борьбы](https://webref.ru/layout/advanced-html-css/detailed-css-positioning):

#### Clearfix

Бутстрап задаёт классу `.row` такие свойства:

```
.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.row:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что класса `.row-fluid` в [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) нет.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="success">Продолжить</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Overflow

Если добавить родительскому блоку свойство `overflow: hidden;`, то он рассчитает свою высоту с учётом плавающих потомков:

```css
.well {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
            <div>
              text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="success">Продолжить</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема была в row-fluid, добавьте данный ответ, я помечу его правильным

Comment: @user193361 Обновил ответ.